# Excel copy values to next available cells in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a spreadsheet and I can't find an answer close enough to what I'm looking for, and my VBA knowledge is fairly basic.

I have a spreadsheet to keep track of who is in what team, and I'd like to have a 'master list' and choose which team the employee is moving into from a drop down list in Column F. I'd like to then copy Cells C,D & E into the next available cell in the range designated for that team, for example Employee A was showing in the team list for Team1, but have now moved to Team2 so I'd like them to be removed from the range set for Team1 and moved to the next available cell in the range set for Team2 (and ideally resort the values in the range). The two sheets are named "Names" and "Teams List".

Is this even possible, especially for a basic understanding of VBA?

Regards,

Cr1kk0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (say) cell `A1` contains your dropdown list with values `Team1`, `Team2` etc, and there are corresponding ranges named Team1, Team2 etc, then:

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Range(Range("A1").Value)
```

defines `myRange` to be the range selected by the current value of the dropdown.

To refer to individual cells within the range, use the `Cells` property, e.g.:

```
myRange.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Fred Bloggs"
```

which refers to the cell in the third row and first column of myRange.

To find a value within the range, use (e.g.):

```
pos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Fred Bloggs", myRange, 0)
```

which returns the position within myRange of the cell whose contents exactly match "Fred Bloggs" (but an error if there is no such cell).

Comment: Thanks nekomatic. My apologies, i forgot to expand on ranges. I'm alright with finding the next available cell in a column, but by range i meant that the cells in the workshhet i want to copy to are a1-a12 are named range1, cells a17-a25 are range2, cells c13-c20 are range3

Comment: See my edit, hope this addresses what you were actually after?

Comment: Thanks nekomatic! Will post how it goes